# Is it possible to change the CSS style attributes of a web page when loading it in a JEditorPane

Tags: java

I'm loading a web page into a JEditorPane and need to change the background color of the page . Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

public void setBackground(Color bg)

Sets the background color of this component. You can use a method inherit from class javax.swing.JComponent.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4a_GUI_2.html#zz-1.5

Comment: Tried that didn't work. It only changes the color behind the web page